# How to manage such animation in UITableView or with any other control?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i want to implement delete row with animation like [this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzohZkN9K1M)

[image]

Now deleting of row is easy task now i have question regarding how to manage animation like above video with UITable or any other control.

i refer some [instance method.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for tableview.

But in this, i am not getting how to manage animation like move row on touch in tableview.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The animation would need to be a custom implementation. I would recommend having a subview on the UITableViewCell (the subview would be the red, the table view cell's background would be the black), and place a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the subview. You'd then need to move the subview as the user pans (in the gesture recognizer's method that is triggered), and do the math to know when the row should be deleted. Then you would just use the native iOS delete row method:

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: yes as per your answer, i know we can get animation on delete. But i required animation like move cell on touch. Check above code`s link it`s good custom control.

Answer (score 0):

I found such cool custom control based on UITableView which provide exact animation i actually required.

You can found code [here.](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo/downloads)